# Log4j Logger garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, log4j

Is there a way to force a Log4j `Logger` to be released/garbage collected?

In general, does Log4j "hang on" to `Logger` references in some `static` collection?

I see the `Logger.shutdown()` method, which is deprecated and refers to `LoggerManager.shutdown()`, which doesn't sound like it addresses a single `Logger` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the log4j source code yourself.

Based on a quick trawl, I think the answers are:

> Is there a way to force a Log4j Logger to be released/garbage collected?

Not with that level of granularity.  The only thing I could find was a method (`Heirarchy.clear()`) that releases all loggers ... and destroy the logging hierarchy in the process.

> In general, does Log4j "hang on" to Logger references in some static collection?

Yes.  And the collection doesn't use weak references ...